# Azure Communication UI Library - Xamarin Forms Error

Tags: xamarin.forms, azure-communication-services

I have been trying to use azure communication services mainly video chatting in my Xamarin Forms application. I have downloaded the aar files via the `downloadJarScript.sh` script. However, I cannot seem to fix the error below:

> Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State Error
> drawable_azure_communication_ui_calling_corner_bottom_left_top_right_radius_rectangle_4dp.xml.flat:
> error: failed to open file.
> "drawable_azure_communication_ui_calling_corner_bottom_left_top_right_radius_rectangle_4dp.xml.flat:
> error: failed to open file.".
> CommunicationCallingXamarinSampleApp.Android

Comment: you have to post the relevant code.  We have no idea what you are doing

Comment: @Jason I'm trying to run the azure-communication-ui-library sample [link](https://github.com/Azure/communication-ui-library-android#prerequisites). I followed the instructions to run on Android, but I cannot seem to find the source of the error mentioned above